# WPF How to affect the scroll amount of a scrollview

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TabControl`, which has a `TabPanel`, which is put inside a `ScrollViewer`.

```
<Style x:Key="TabCtrl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <RepeatButton
                        x:Name="ScrolltoLeft_Btn"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand}"
                        CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=sv}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ScrolltoLeft}" />

                    <ScrollViewer
                        x:Name="sv"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"

                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

                        <TabPanel
                            x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                            Panel.ZIndex="1"
                            IsItemsHost="true"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
                    </ScrollViewer>

                    <ContentPresenter
                        x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        ContentSource="SelectedContent"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />

                    <RepeatButton
                        x:Name="ScrolltoRight_Btn"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="2"

                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineRightCommand}"
                        CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=sv}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ScrolltoRight}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

When I press the repeat buttons, the amount which is scrolled is minimal, a small portion of the width of one `TabItem`.

I want this to be bigger. I want (at a minimal) to scroll the width of `TabItem`.

I already played with the `CanContentScroll` property of a `ScrollViewer`, but that doesn't change anything.

I also tried to change the `SmallChange` property on the horizontal scrollbar, but that also has no impact.

```
myTab.ApplyTemplate();
var scrollviewer = myTab.Template.FindName("sv", myTab) as ScrollViewer;
if (scrollviewer != null)
{
    scrollviewer.ApplyTemplate();
    _scrollBar = scrollviewer.Template.FindName("PART_HorizontalScrollBar", scrollviewer) as ScrollBar;
    if (_scrollBar != null)
    {
        _scrollBar.SmallChange = 0.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried binding the Command of the RepeatButton to `PageRightCommand` and `PageLeftCommand`? You can customize the amount of change with the [RangeBase.LargeChange Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.largechange?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @ChristianMurschall, I already tried the SmallChange, but I now also tried to Large change with pageleft page right commands, but also no solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SmallChange` property of a WPF `ScrollBar` is only considered for scrolling when the scroll bar is stand-alone (that means, **not** in a `ScrollViewer`). Since you are using a `ScrollViewer` in your control template, this will never work. A `ScrollViewer` will always apply a default small change of 16 units.

You have two options now:

- Implement `IScrollInfo` in a wrapper class (e.g. derived from a `ContentControl`), attach it to the scroll viewer as content, put the `TabPanel` inside of this customized wrapper class, set the `CanContentScroll` property of the `ScrollViewer` to `true`. Now you have full control of the scrolling.
- Use a little hack: create an external `ScrollBar` and let it scroll the `ScrollViewer`.

I show you the second approach:

Below your `ScrollViewer`, add a new scroll bar:

```
<ScrollBar 
    x:Name="myScrollBar"
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal"
    Visibility="Collapsed"
    Tag="{Binding ElementName=sv}"
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="{Binding ScrollableWidth, ElementName=sv}"
    ViewportSize="{Binding ViewportWidth, ElementName=sv}"
    Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=sv, Mode=OneWay}"
    SmallChange="100"
    Scroll="MyScrollBar_OnScroll"/>
```

You can change the `SmallChange` property as you wish.

Update both scroll commands to target this scroll bar, not the `ScrollViewer`:

```
<RepeatButton
    <!-- ... -->
    CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=myScrollBar}"/>
```

Finally, you need to connect the external scroll bar to the `ScrollViewer`:

```
void MyScrollBar_OnScroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
  ScrollBar sb = (ScrollBar)sender;
  (sb.Tag as ScrollViewer)?.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(e.NewValue);
}
```

(You might want to make a `Behavior` out of this to keep the code-behind empty, to avoid using the `Tag` property, and to allow reusability).

Comment: This is brilliant. I will test it ASAP. Thx a lot!

Comment: Like a charm, I will try to create an attached property/behavior out of it. Not an expert in that area though.